# New Unity version copies the settings of previous version

Tags: unity

I use Ubuntu 20.04.
When I download a new version of Unity 3D through Unity Hub, this new version automatically takes the settings of the previous version. I have installed Unity 2020.1, and I am facing the same problem. I created a new project, but it written in 2020.1 that I used preview package. I didn't even installed any package in Unity 2020.1. I did install preview package in 2019.4. But I didn't even open the project with 2020.1. I only have one project with 2020.1. The new project I just created.
 I asking help because I faced this issue when I first installed 2019.1, 2019.2, etc.
How can I flx it? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem to be 'fixed' exactly? Because this sounds like intended, designed behavior...

Comment: Have the Default Unity settings on each newly installed version. New Unity version with new project often shows error log of another project. It must not be like that

Comment: It copies over the previous settings because that's how everyone wants it to work. "Shows error log of another project" does not make any sense. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Kevin, it is not normal to find error of a project in another new project. It means there is a file open somewhere and every project visit it.

Comment: @Achie1 Perhaps it would help if you told us what the specific error is.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the preview packages warning when starting my first Unity 2020 project.

Clicking on the drop-down arrow in this warning message allowed me to select the option "Show Preview Packages"

This opened the Package Manager, and showed that the lone preview package was TextMeshPro 3.0.0-preview.10

At the bottom of the window was an option to Update to the current stable version, 3.0.0

Clicking this resolved the warning about preview packages.

I'd recommend following similar steps for any preview packages you have in your project, unless you deliberately want to test out changes only available in the preview.